# Accessing JSON data after Axios get request

Tags: javascript, json, axios, discord

I've been trying to make a Discord Bot that works with the Shoppy API (https://shoppy.dev/). I'm completely new to Javascript - but not new to coding!

I did some research on Axios and have managed to use it to pull a list of orders from a Shoppy account. The problem is, there's a ton of this data I only want to display some of it to the user. I've had to redact some info in the code below but this is what I have:

```
        case 'orders':
            async function makeRequest() {
                const config = {
                    method: 'get',
                    url: 'https://shoppy.gg/api/v1/orders/',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'REDACTED - MY API KEY',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
                    }
                }
                axios(config)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    });
            }

            makeRequest();
            break;
```

This produces the below output in the console. I've only listed some of the info here just to show the format but you get the general idea:

```
Bot Online
[
  {
    id: 'REDACTED',
    pay_id: null,
    product_id: 'REDACTED',
    coupon_id: null,
    price: 3,
    currency: 'CAD',
    exchange_rate: null,
    email: 'REDACTED',
    delivered: 1,
    confirmations: 1,
    required_confirmations: 1,
```

My problem is - I can't figure out how to take just the data from the 'email' for example and display it to the user. I've spent hours trying different ways but the console always just shows 'undefined'.

I feel like it's a super simple thing and I'm just not getting something. Does anyone have any advice? To give a bit more context for this piece of code, the user is writing '!order' and the bot will respond with a list of their orders - but I only want the bot to display something like 'Order ID', 'Product Name, 'Email'. So I don't need all of the data that gets pulled.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, if your issue was resolved by any of the below answers, consider marking one as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

The request returns an array. So you need to iterate over it to obtain all the elements. You can use a for loop or the map function to do so in the response callback.

```
axios(config).then(response => {
   console.log(response.data);
   //Add the for loop or the map operator here
})
```

To use the for loop:

```
for(let x of response.data){
   //x gives you an individual item. Do whatever you want with it.
   // x.email gives you the email
}
```

To use the map operator:

```
var emails = response.data.map(x => {
    return x.email;
});
//emails contains the array of all emails
```

You can add your own validation in the for loop or the map operator to select appropriate emails...

Comment: This actually works perfectly thanks a ton!!! I'll do some reading on maps to have a better understanding, but I tested just for emails quick and was able to pull them.